# LightningChart JS: Assigning different MouseButton to Axis Interaction

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

We have a legacy desktop application with charts that have a specific handling of axis interaction our users are accustomed to.

Web-based interaction is now being moved to LightningChartJS. However, the API does not seem to offer to customize its behavior based on the mouse button.

Among others, we would like to enable panning an Axis using the left mouse button instead of RMB. [The doc specifically references RMB though](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/axis.html#setaxisinteractionpanbydragging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LightningChart JS v3.0.0 this is possible with the use of [`overrideInteractionMouseButtons`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.3.3/interfaces/lightningchartoptions.html#overrideinteractionmousebuttons) initialisation option.

```js
 const lcjs = lightningChart({
     // LightningChartOptions
     overrideInteractionMouseButtons: {
         chartXYPanMouseButton: 0, // LMB
         chartXYRectangleZoomFitMouseButton: 2, // RMB
     }
 })
```

See [`OverrideInteractionMouseButtons`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.3.3/interfaces/overrideinteractionmousebuttons.html) for details on which interactions can be moved to different mouse buttons.

Comment: Sweet, updating to 3.0 has been on our backlog for a while, this will help prioritization.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to customize the behavior of the mouse buttons for Axis. We're planning to add this functionality at a later date.